# is offline browsing bad for SEO?

Tags: seo

i know that "how many times people visit a page has a good effect on SEO", so what about PWAs with offline browsing ?

assume that we have an article on our PWA, if a user use the cached article several times in different days, it can't be tracked, because it's offline. so what about SEO that has a factor of how many people visited that page? and how much time they spend in that page?

Comment: Please cite your source for  "how many times people visit a page has a good effect on SEO".  [Traffic isn't widely recognized to be an SEO factor](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/64861/).

Comment: looking into my christal glass i think you mean user metrics. So, if you build your site or PWA so that Google gets user actions into knowledge, than it it shouldn't be a "bad" factor. But, however, nobody knows about what exactly Google thinks about your user's actions...

Comment: If you're really worried about whether Google know you have offline trafic on your app you can plug [Google Analytics App + web. ](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/getting-started-with-google-analytics-app-web/) It's a pretty recent feature. But as the previous commenters have said, it's not a ranking factor.